# tomcat 8 catalina.properties add variable

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, environment-variables

I need to read an enviromental variable from Tomcat app. I tried to do:

```
/opt/tomcat/conf/catalina.properties
```

addint at the end:

```
my.special.variable=some_value
```

and reading it by

```
System.getenv("my.special.variable")
```

I get null

**Note**

I have several defined at OS level (linux ubuntu) but the result of getting them is tomcat root - /opt/tomcat.

For example :

with `printenv` I can see variable HOME (also with echo $HOME). Running code from a program that is outside of the tomcat - the result is correct - /home/user.

Exactly the same code in app deployed in tomcat return - /opt/tomcat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define variables in `setenv.sh`(Linux/UNIX) or `setenv.bat` (Windows).  Define the variables in the appropriate manner for the O/S you are running on.  For Linux/UNIX you will need to export the variables.  You can also define them in the environment you start Tomcat from.

You can also create an `appenv.sh` or `appenv.bat` file for application (local) changes.  Read the existing `setenv.sh` or `setenv.bat` file for details.

Periods and hyphens are not valid for environment variables.  Traditionally, the names are transformed by upper-casing the name and changing periods and hyphens to underscores. That would give the the name `MY_SPECIAL_VARIABLE`. This would be defined with a line like:

```
export MY_SPECIAL_VARIABLE=some.value
```

You can also define Java system properties by adding a string '-Dmy.special.variable=some_value`to the command line used to start Tomcat.   This is done in the same file.  In`setenv.sh` you would add a line like:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dmy.special.variable=some_value"
```

You can also use this file to tune the Java configuration. If `JAVA_OPTS` system variable is defined in the environment used to launch Tomcat, its value will be added to the command line.

If you use a Java system property you retrieve with a call to `System.getProperty`.  This would be coded like:

```
    System.getProperty("my.special.variable");
```

Comment: I have several defined at OS level (linux) but the result of them is tomcat root - /opt/tomcat.

Comment: @VasilKoicev see comment on other response.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables aren't Tomcat properties.

AFAIK you cannot use the properties inside the actual code, just in e.g. server.xml.

If you want to use environment variables that you can retrieve with System.getenv, you'll need to define them with your operating system; that quite depends. A classic Linux example would in `/etc/default/tomcat` or in the systemd service.

Comment: I have several defined at OS level (linux) but the result of them is tomcat root - /opt/tomcat.

Comment: @VasilKoicev If you are running Tomcat as a root service, the variables may be cleared when you invoke root to start the service..  Find `setenv.sh` under `/opt/tomcat` and define your properties there or in `appenv.sh` in the same directory.  I would use `appenv.sh`.  Use of Java system properties is more common than OS properties.

Comment: great it's working!